# Developing an extension for browsers: is it better to start with Chrome or with Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I have to develop a simple app for the two major browsers: Chrome and Firefox. The app should only connect to a remote service and sends data to it (logically it is very simple).

I've never written an app for any browser, but I know HTML, Javascript (and other server-sided languages).

My question is: should I start to develop the app for Chrome? Or should I start with Firefox? I'm asking that because I'm wondering that maybe there are some porting tools for these two browsers...

Answer (score 3):

i think its much easier in firefox because you can control absolutely everything. what are you trying to make your addon do? i can probably give you a template.

chrome addons are limited in capability and the workarounds to compensate make it a headache. but because its so limited there isnt much you can do so its not hard to make, can copy anyones addon and change a few words.